How to Bypass the 5000 Folder/File Item Limit for a SharePoint Document Library Folder?
I recognize that existing issues and examples such as #392 and Office-365 REST Client example read_all.py tackles how to incrementally query more than 5000 items from a SharePoint list, but I found no solutions on how to similarly incrementally query more than 5000 items from a document library. Most solutions that I found online sought to resolve this issue through editing the site permissions such as increasing the file query limit, but I have no access to such permissions. Is there a way to get around these restrictions using existing SharePoint Python code?

If anyone is interested, below is the code I am using:
class SHARE_LIB:
    __context = ""

  class ShareItem:
    __name = ""
    __type = ""
    __last_modified = ""
    __relative_url = ""
  
    def __init__(self, name, type, last_modified, relative_url):
        self.__name = name
        self.__type = type
        self.__last_modified = last_modified
        self.__relative_url = relative_url
    
    def get_name(self):          return self.__name
    def get_type(self):          return self.__type
    def get_last_modified(self): return self.__last_modified
    def get_relative_url(self):  return self.__relative_url

  def __init__(self, context):
    self.__context = context
    
  def get_folder_small(self, relative_url, recursive = False):
      item_list = []
  
      try:
          folder = self.__context.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(relative_url)
          sub_folders = (folder.get_folders(recursive).execute_query())               # ERROR HERE
          files = folder.get_files(recursive).execute_query()                         # ERROR HERE
      except Exception as e:
          print("------------------------------------------------------")
          print(f"ERROR Class: {e.__class__.__name__}")
          print(f"ERRROR: {e}")
          
          input("Press any key to continue...")
          exit(1)
  
      for folder in sub_folders:
          item_name = folder.properties["Name"].strip()
          item_type = FileSystemObjectType.Folder
          item_last_modified = localize_sharepoint_modified(folder.properties["TimeLastModified"])
          item_url = folder.properties["ServerRelativeUrl"].strip()
      
          item = self.ShareItem(item_name, item_type, item_last_modified, item_url)
          item_list.append(item)
  
      for file in files:
          item_name = file.properties["Name"].strip()
          item_type = FileSystemObjectType.File
          item_last_modified = localize_sharepoint_modified(file.properties["TimeLastModified"])
          item_url = file.properties["ServerRelativeUrl"].strip()
  
          item = self.ShareItem(item_name, item_type, item_last_modified, item_url)
          item_list.append(item)
  
      item_list.sort(key = lambda x: x.get_name().upper())
      return item_list

ERROR when I run the code:
ERROR Class: ClientRequestException
ERRROR: ('-2147024860, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException', 'The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold.', "500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: https://fsrao.sharepoint.com/sites/<site_name>/_api/Web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('<relative_url>')?$select=Folders&$expand=Folders")

